# Could anyone explain the return of linalg.lstsq in details?

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

Though the [linalg.lstsq document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) is offered. I still feel hard to understand since it is not quite detailed.

> x : {(N,), (N, K)} ndarray
>
> Least-squares solution. If b is two-dimensional, the solutions are in
>   the K columns of x.
>
> residuals : {(1,), (K,), (0,)} ndarray
>
> Sums of residuals; squared Euclidean 2-norm for each column in b -
>   a*x. If the rank of a is < N or M <= N, this is an empty array. If b
>   is 1-dimensional, this is a (1,) shape array. Otherwise the shape is
>   (K,).
>
> rank : int
>
> Rank of matrix a.
>
> s : (min(M, N),) ndarray
>
> Singular values of a.

I tried to observe the output. But I only figure out the rank is 2. For the rest, I don't get why it is so.

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([-1, 0.2, 0.9, 2.1])
A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
print(A)
print('-------------------------')
print(np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None))
```

Gives

```
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [2. 1.]
 [3. 1.]]
-------------------------
(array([ 1.  , -0.95]), array([0.05]), 2, array([4.10003045, 1.09075677]))
```

I don't understand what the tuples, "(N, ), (N, K), (1,), (K,), (0,), (M, N)", represent in the document.

For example, `np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]` would be `array([ 1.  , -0.95])` How does it relate to {(N,), (N, K)}?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those tuples are the possible shapes of inputs and outputs.
In your example, `A.shape = (4, 2)` and `y.shape = (4,)`.
Looking at the documentation, `M = 4`, `N = 2`, and we are dealing with the cases without `K`.
So the output's shapes should be `x.shape = (N,) = (2,)`, `residuals.shape = (1,)`, `s.shape = (min(M, N),) = (2,)`.

Let's look at the outputs one at a time

```
>>> x, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)
```

`x` is the least square solution of `A @ x = y`, so it minimises `np.linalg.norm(A @ x - y)**2`:

```
>>> A.T @ (A @ x - y)
array([1.72084569e-15, 2.16493490e-15])
```

The other outputs are there to tell you how good this solution is and how susceptible it is to numerical errors.

`residuals` is the squared norm of the mis-match between `A @ x` and `y`:

```
>>> np.linalg.norm(A @ x - y)**2
0.04999999999999995
>>> residuals[0]
0.04999999999999971
```

`rank` is the rank of `A`:

```
np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)
2
>>> rank
2
```

`s` contains the singular values of `A`

```
>>> np.linalg.svd(A, compute_uv=False)
array([4.10003045, 1.09075677])
>>> s
array([4.10003045, 1.09075677])
```

Are you familiar with the mathematical concepts?